# REQUIRED process [open_manipulator_dynamixel_controller-2] has died!

Tags: ros, manipulator, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just tried to operate open manipulator system by using two motor(MX-106).
When I launch that code, the following error occur.

```
roslaunch open_manipulator_dynamixel_ctrl dynamixel_controller.launch
```

I already let the USB accss allow, but it is not working too.
What would I do to solve this error??

```
started roslaunch server http://localhost:*****/
SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

    /baud_rate: 1000000
    /device_name: /dev/ttyUSB0
    /rosdistro: kinetic
    /rosversion: 1.12.12
    /scan_range: 10

NODES
/
open_manipulator_dynamixel_controller (open_manipulator_dynamixel_ctrl/dynamixel_controller)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [5590]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
setting /run_id to *****
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [5603]
started core service [/rosout]
process[open_manipulator_dynamixel_controller-2]: started with pid [5609]
[ INFO] [1520408424.601165791]: open_manipulator_dynamixel_controller : Init OK!
================================================================================REQUIRED process [open_manipulator_dynamixel_controller-2] has died!
process has died [pid 5609, exit code -11, cmd /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/lib/open_manipulator_dynamixel_ctrl/dynamixel_controller __name:=open_manipulator_dynamixel_controller __log:=/home/user/.ros/log/.../open_manipulator_dynamixel_controller-2.log].
log file: /home/user/.ros/log/.../open_manipulator_dynamixel_controller-2*.log
Initiating shutdown!

[open_manipulator_dynamixel_controller-2] killing on exit
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284670/required-process-%5Bopen_manipulator_dynamixel_controller-2%5D-has-died!/) by [epiphanyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33777/epiphanyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-07**:
Just an observation:

> ```
> setting /run_id to *****
> ```

why remove this from the `roslaunch` output? It's a randomly generated UUID. There's no way to relate that to any specific machine/person/location.

**Comment by [epiphanyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33777/epiphanyan/) on 2018-03-07**:
I don't know that exactly. So I remove that. Is it necessary to know that for solving the problem? If so, I will post my error message again. Thanks for letting me know.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-07**:
No, it's most likely not important. Neither is my question, I was just surprised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi :)

`open_manipulator_dynamixel_controller` is compatible with protocol 2.0.
This video would be help you to replace it to MX-106(2.0)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=68&v=q_gAewi_dyY

And this is wiki page for it

http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/dxl/mx/mx-106-2/

---

Originally posted by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) with karma: 811 on 2018-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0